# Can't get prepend ajax content faded in

Tags: jquery, ajax, prepend

I want the content my ajax call is returning to be faded in, but I can't get it to work.

**The ajax response is html:**

```
<div id="com_loaded">
  <div id="com_loaded_poster"><a href="#"><?=$row['user_name']?></a></div>
  <div id="com_loaded_text"><?=$row['comment_text']?></div>
</div>
```

**it is prepended to the following div:**

```
<div id="messages">

            <?

            $sql = "SELECT *
                    FROM items_comments, users
                    WHERE items_comments.item_id = '".$id."'
                    AND items_comments.user_id = users.user_id
                    ORDER BY comment_id DESC";
            $result = $Db->sQuery($sql);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            ?>

            <div id="com_loaded">
                <div id="com_loaded_height"></div>
                <div id="com_loaded_userpic"><a href="#" class="tooltip"><img src="<?=$row['user_pic']?>" class="img_poster" /><span><?=$row['user_name']?></span></a></div>
                <div id="com_loaded_content">
                    <div id="com_loaded_poster"><a href="#"><?=$row['user_name']?></a></div>
                    <div id="com_loaded_text"><?=$row['comment_text']?></div>
                </div>
                <div id="com_loaded_divide"></div> 
            </div>
            <?

            }

            ?>


            </div>
```

And I'm trying to fade in the prepend the following way:

```
       <script>
    $(function() {
        $(".submit-comment").click(function() {

            var text = $(".txtinput").val();
            var itemid = "<?=$id?>";
            var userid = "<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>";
            var dataString = 'text=' + text + '&userid=' + userid + '&itemid=' + itemid;

            if(text == '') {
                $('#content_error1').fadeIn(250);
                $('#content_error1').delay(1500).fadeOut(500);
            } else {



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/comments.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(html){
                /*  $("#messages").prepend(html).fadeIn(2000); */

                $(html).hide().prependTo("#messages").fadeIn(1000);​
                }
            }); 
            }
            return false; 
        });
    }); 
  </script>
```

the line:

```
 $(html).hide().prependTo("#messages").fadeIn(1000);
```

doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems working check http://jsfiddle.net/9NHfE/

Comment: What's not working for you about it? No fade or not inserted in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using prepend. now it's working